# Call a subprocess

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have to call an executable file in Ubuntu... Just learned how to make this work by using `subprocess.Popen` in windows. Now, I need to repeat this step in Ubuntu.

I have used the following Python command:

```
a=subprocess.Popen("filename.exe",shell=0)
```

The return is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/untitled0.py", line 29, in <module>
    a=subprocess.Popen("filename.exe",shell=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

If I change `shell=1`, there are no complaints, but no output files are generated either.

I have checked the type of this file using `file filename.exe`
It returned:

> filename.exe: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),
>   dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, not
>   stripped

So is it possible to call it using `subprocess.Popen` in Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you attempting to run a 64-bit binary on a 32-bit host? Could you show the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: It seems like my Ubuntu is a 32 bit, which might cause me problem.. May I know what is uname -a?

Comment: It is a command which prints information about the host, including the OS, host name, kernel version, compile time of the kernel and the architecture (from which one can tell if it is a ). On my 32-bit laptop it prints `Linux radiance 2.6.26-2-686 #1 SMP Thu Jan 27 00:28:05 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux` while on my 64-bit server it prints `Linux red 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 16 16:22:28 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My said Linux th-VirtualBox 3.2.0-24-generic-pae #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 10:47:59 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux So I should try a 32 bit exe file.

Comment: Yes, that is a 32-bit system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickly reading the python docs, it looks  like your doing the right thing, so the . How  about trying to exec say /bin/false which should be a known working exe on your system. If that works, then your exe is likely wrong ( perhaps 64bit on a 32 bit system)

Comment: It did not complain by feeding /bin/false, so it seems like my exe is wrong. In addition, what is the difference between shell=0 and shell=1. Thanks

Comment: If shell=1, you are not executing a file,your passing a string to your shell to be evaluated (.e.g "ls -la ~/")